# sss_ssh_authorizedkeys returns error code 13 when called from sshd

Tags: ssh, sssd, freeipa

I'm using a FreeIPA server configured with SSH keys added to users.  I am trying to get servers to authenticate using the ssh keys from the IPA server, so I don't have to manage as many authorized_keys files.

I can confirm that the keys are added and retrievable using `sss_ssh_authorizedkeys <user>` from the command line, which returns the appropriate keys for each user when queried. However, when sshd runs the command, `sss_ssh_authorizedkeys` fails with error code 13.

My test system is my CentOS IPA server.

I added the following snippet to my `sshd_config` to enable this configuration:

```
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/bin/sss_ssh_authorizedkeys
AuthorizedKeysCommandUser nobody
```

I have also tried the `AuthorizedKeysCommandUser` as root to make sure it wasn't a permissions problem.

I've googled my error, which returns a single result from an IRC archive where the end result (from what I can tell) was that the solution was emailed to the asker.  I thought it might have been a problem with SELinux (which has plagued me in web server scenarios), but searching for "`ssh`", "`sshd`", or "`authorizedkeys`" yields nothing out of the ordinary that I could see.  I'm also not super good at reading auth logs, so I'm not ruling out SELinux as the culprit here.

Here is a snippet from the log generated by `sshd -ddd` on the IPA box:

```
Connection from 10.77.1.198 port 56579 on 10.77.1.20 port 22
debug1: Client protocol version 2.0; client software version OpenSSH_7.5
debug1: match: OpenSSH_7.5 pat OpenSSH* compat 0x04000000
debug1: Enabling compatibility mode for protocol 2.0
debug1: Local version string SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.6.1
debug1: SELinux support enabled [preauth]
debug1: permanently_set_uid: 74/74 [preauth]
debug1: list_hostkey_types: ssh-rsa,ecdsa-sha2-nistp256,ssh-ed25519 [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT sent [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_KEXINIT received [preauth]
debug1: kex: client->server chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none [preauth]
debug1: kex: server->client chacha20-poly1305@openssh.com <implicit> none [preauth]
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=64 dh_need=64 [preauth]
debug1: kex: curve25519-sha256@libssh.org need=64 dh_need=64 [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_KEX_ECDH_INIT [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS sent [preauth]
debug1: expecting SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS [preauth]
debug1: SSH2_MSG_NEWKEYS received [preauth]
debug1: KEX done [preauth]
debug1: userauth-request for user [username] service ssh-connection method none [preauth]
debug1: attempt 0 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: PAM: initializing for "[username]"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_RHOST to "10.77.1.198"
debug1: PAM: setting PAM_TTY to "ssh"
debug1: userauth-request for user [username] service ssh-connection method publickey [preauth]
debug1: attempt 1 failures 0 [preauth]
debug1: test whether pkalg/pkblob are acceptable [preauth]
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 0/0 (e=0/0)
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 0/0 (e=0/0)
Found matching RSA key: 2a:be:8a:c9:4f:62:7a:66:99:70:c1:ca:02:17:ee:94
AuthorizedKeysCommand /usr/bin/sss_ssh_authorizedkeys exited on signal 13
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
debug1: temporarily_use_uid: 1954400001/1954400001 (e=0/0)
debug1: trying public key file /home/[username]/.ssh/authorized_keys
debug1: Could not open authorized keys '/home/[username]/.ssh/authorized_keys': No such file or directory
debug1: restore_uid: 0/0
Failed publickey for [username] from 10.77.1.198 port 56579 ssh2: RSA 2a:be:8a:c9:4f:62:7a:66:99:70:c1:ca:02:17:ee:94
debug1: userauth-request for user [username] service ssh-connection method keyboard-interactive [preauth]
debug1: attempt 2 failures 1 [preauth]
debug1: keyboard-interactive devs  [preauth]
debug1: auth2_challenge: user=[username] devs= [preauth]
debug1: kbdint_alloc: devices 'pam' [preauth]
debug1: auth2_challenge_start: trying authentication method 'pam' [preauth]
Postponed keyboard-interactive for [username] from 10.77.1.198 port 56579 ssh2 [preauth]
```

Answer (score 1):

The sss_ssh_authorizedkeys binary is just a dumb wrapper which doesn't even log much and just talks to sssd's sss_ssh process. So the best way to find out is to put debug_level into the [ssh] section in sssd.conf and take a look into the sssd logs..